# What force needs to be applied to produce twice as much acceleration as already present in a body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

Let the current body of mass $m$ be moving with acceleration $a$, produced by applying $F = ma$.

So, I thought that if I apply force $F$ again (same magnitude and direction as before), I would get acceleration $a$ (as $a = F/m$). So, $a$ added to the already present $a$ would give $2a$. So, I answered to this question: "Same as before force needs to be applied". But, it turned out my answer was wrong.

I also saw [What does an applied force on an already accelerating object do?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118597/what-does-an-applied-force-on-an-already-accelerating-object-do), but it seemed to show my answer correct, when it actually isn't.

**EDIT**: Their is no friction between the mass and surface on which it is moving.

Comment: Acceleration *stops* when there is no force. There is no "acceleration present in a body". How would "applying the same force" lead to twice the acceleration, given that $F = ma$ still holds?

Comment: It's hard to comment without knowing exactly what the question was. If I was setting that question in an exam I'd expect the answer to be $2F$.

Comment: your difficulty comes from the word 'again'. To gain a constant acceleration, you need to apply a constant force. If you stop to apply that force, the speed doesn't increase more and stays constant. Edit: said before by ACuriousMind, sorry

Comment: Acceleration isn't present in a body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object will not accelerate without an non-zero net force. If you accelerate an object with a constant force, and you keep applying that force, then the object will keep accelerating at the same rate. The answer is twice the force. $$a = \dfrac{F}{m}$$ $$2a = \dfrac{2F}{m}$$

Comment: I see where I went wrong. The key is that an *object stops accelerating* when the force is removed. Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. By F=ma You know that Force is directly proportional to Acceleration . If force is increased 2 times the acceleration WILL increase 2 times

Your answer is correct! It will increase as F increases!